# Receive a notification when the user open an email - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, web

I building an application using rails, and I wanna know if is possible to write a code which allows me to be notified or something like that when the user open an email sent through my application. I need to track that information. When I sent an email, I need know. The question  to be answered by my app is "Did they read it?"

Tips in others languages would be ok to me!

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English =))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to embed a hidden image (1x1 pixel) into your email content with a bunch of query string parameters attached to it.

Then within your application, monitor for requests to this image and parse out the query string parameters.

Main problem with this however if if users email client has images disabled, they can read the email but you won't be notified.

Comment: Generally better to add a real image, like a logo or something, otherwise it's blatantly obvious.

Comment: Yeah I get your point. I still looking for another approach. But I'll try what you said... Thanks man!

Comment: This is the general industry practice. Places like MailChimp that do professional email-campaign tracking also use this same approach.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark it as the answer if it helps :)